# How to use module method in a class?

Tags: ruby

What's wrong with this code?

```
module A
  def self.foo
    puts 'Hello'
  end
  class B
    def test
      foo
    end
  end
end

A::B.new.test
```

It says:

```
test.rb:7:in `test': undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<A::B:0x007fcbe29e3580> (NameError)
    from test.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write `A.foo` to call foo the way it has been defined.

Alternatively, you could remove `self.` from the definition of foo and write `include A` in the definition of B.  It depends on what exactly you want to do and if you want the module method to have access to private data of the object.

Answer (score 0):

`B` is just another constant inside `A` module. Modules are just sacks of methods and constants, class inside them does not automatically inherit from them, just stays in that namespace. To access the `A::foo` method from a `B` you can just:

```
module A
  def self.foo
    puts 'Hello'
  end

  class B
    def test
      A.foo
    end
  end
end

A::B.new.test
```

Alternatively, you can either `include` or `extend` `A` into `B`:

```
module C
  def c_method() 'hey I come from C' end
end

class D
  include C # include C's method as instance variable
end

D.new.c_method
=> 'hey I come from C'

class E
  extend C # extend C's method into E as class methods
end

E.c_method
=> 'hey I come from C'

module F
  # this is a module method, can't be extended or included
  def self.f_method() 'hi I come from F' end
end

class G
  extend F
  include F
  def my_method() F.f_method end # you can call it directly anyway
end

G.f_method
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `f_method' for G:Class 
G.new.f_method
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `f_method' for #<G:0x0000000c06c668>
G.my_method
=> "hi I come from F"
```